# Does not storing length of strings and other such values make program slower?

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, stl

Here I have two code functions with me:

```
string func1(string s) {
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<=s.length();j++){
                cout << i <<"\t"<<j<<endl;
            }
        }
        return "test";
    }

string func2(string s) {
        int n = s.length();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<=n;j++){
                cout << i <<"\t"<<j<<endl;
            }
        }
        return "test";
    }
```

Both do the same thing. Print values of combinations of i and j. But I have always wondered, does not storing s.length() in a variable like n trigger recomputation every time we mention it in our code. If this is true then func2 should run faster than func1.

Or is it the case that C++ compilers and other programming language compilers have some clever way of detecting this and make sure that this recomputation doesn't happen when converting to machine language?

Then I have another question, do functions like vector.size() or string.length() give the size and length respectively in constant time (by keeping it precomputed each time a insertion or deletion happens and then just serving up the value when called for in vector.size or string.length) or do they traverse through the whole data structure to compute this on each call to the method.

I understand that all these would be pretty elementary doubts but I have never seen programmers talk about this and I wanna be sure. My limited experience in C++ doesn't help either.

Comment: This is implementation specific. Most modern compilers will detect common patterns as the one you have here and optimize for them, but you'll have to test your setup to know for sure if it applies there.

Comment: Every standard library container that has a `size` function is requires it to be an O(1) operation.

Comment: @NicolBolas does same go for .length() as well? is string.length also O(1)?

Comment: the cost of doing `<< endl` is so much bigger than `length()` (or even the rest of the snippet).

Comment: @VaibhavChopra: `length` just calls `size`.

Comment: @NicolBolas While a pedantic distinction, it used to be that containers were required to have constant time `begin` and `end` iterators, but not explicitly the `size` function (though all implementations that I know of would, of course). Not sure if the requirement for `size` was spelled out in recent standards.

Comment: @Jeffrey I did not know that endl is more time expensive... I was just taught that endl is yet another way of inserting a new line, just like the escape sequence \n

Comment: IMHO, setting the length to a constant variable reduces the quantity of calls to `std::length()`.  However, the compiler may perform the same magic at higher optimization levels.  I prefer to help out the compiler. :-)